# HDD filesystem turned to RAW after freeze / manual reboot

Tags: hard-drive

I have an unfortunate situation here.

I'm using a dual boot computer ( Ubuntu - Win10 ) and while I was transferring / writing data on an NTFS HDD on Ubuntu, Ubuntu froze for whatever reason so I had to manually reboot the computer.
After I manually rebooted the computer, the HDD wasn't seen/detected anymore by Ubuntu, and in Windows, it was still seen but as RAW data HDD (still filled with TBs of data but I can't access it anymore) and as it's seen as RAW, no chkdsk command works on it.

Would someone have any suggestions of any process that would help recovering the data?

(as a note : the HDD is docked in a 4 stairs USB3 external docker, the 3 others HDDs works well)

EDIT :
here is results of various tests as suggested :

first with command, the Drive in question (4) is seen but without any partition

[command capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKQZJ.png)

About S.M.A.R.T. status, I tried with CrystalDiskInfo, it didn't detect and list the HDD at all. Then I tried with Hard Disk Sentinel, it detected it but couldn't read anything from it, so no SMART attributes at all.

I Also tried with DMDE. It gave lots of LBA errors, and didn't detected any functionnal partition neither and provided this log file :

```
[devscan]
scan_dev=1:0:11:-1:0x1:512:7814037168:\\?\scsi#disk&ven_st4000dm&prod_004-2cv104#a&72eb970&0&000000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
scan_range="0x0-0x3a3817d6000"
scan_ltrack=1.1:0x0:1.1:806:953964:0xc4de8cdcb7000
scan_ltrackorg=1.1:806:0x3:0x0:0x0:0x3a3817d6000:0x400000
scan_lbps=512
scan_state_sec="block:0x2000;inc:0x4000;first:0x2000;shift:0x2000;sec:0x1d1c0beb0;set:0x0"
scan_modules=0x3
module_flags="10;0x7,0x7,0x7,0x7,0x7,0x7,0x7,0x7,0x7,0x7,"
module_states="10;0x10,0x10,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,"
expgrp="10;0x0,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,"
modselected=1
volselected=-1
volsortcol=3
extarr="145;xml,html,htm,reg,png,pdf,exe,exe,msi,chm,jpeg,jpg,jpe,jfif,jif,jfi,wav,\
gif,rtf,doc,html,htm,7z,vdi,vmdk,mp3,avi,cr2,nef,nrw,dng,tiff,tif,dng,ps,eps,doc,\
xls,ppt,msi,msp,wmv,wma,asf,psd,aiff,aifc,aif,iff,snd,flac,midi,mid,arc,bz2,tbz2,\
tar,ogg,oga,ogv,cab,rar,iso,doc,docx,xlsx,pptx,xls,ppt,ott,odt,otg,odg,otp,odp,ots,\
ods,otc,odc,oti,odi,otf,odf,oth,odm,apk,jar,apk,zip,zipx,jar,mkv,flv,mov,mov,mp4,\
mp4,dll,mui,vhd,vhd,vhdx,vmdk,pst,ost,pab,bmp,m2ts,mts,djvu,djv,doc,docx,pptx,ppt,\
xlsx,xls,doc,xls,ppt,msi,msp,mpeg,mpg,mpe,mpeg,mpg,mpe,mpeg,mpg,mpe,mov,crw,srw,\
raf,orf,jpeg,jpg,jpe,jfif,jif,jfi,mp3,cr3,heic"

[rawscan]
scan_vorg=1.3
scan_modltrack=1.0:0x0:1.3:806:953964:0x7e0ec21211000
scan_modltrackorg=1.3:806:0x0:0x0
ft_opmask=0x3ff
ft_op[gif.]=0x8
ft_op[jpg.]=0x88
ft_op[png.]=0x8
ft_op[pdf.]=0x8
ft_op[zip.]=0x8
ft_op[mpeg.]=0x8
ft_op[.]=0x0
ft_op[xml]=0x0
ft_op[reg]=0x0
ft_op[png]=0x2
ft_op[pdf]=0x0
ft_op[exe-DOS]=0x1
ft_op[exe-Win]=0x0
ft_op[chm]=0x0
ft_op[jpeg]=0x0
ft_op[wav]=0x0
ft_op[gif]=0x2
ft_op[rtf]=0x0
ft_op[html]=0x0
ft_op[7z]=0x2
ft_op[vdi]=0x4
ft_op[vmdk]=0x4
ft_op[mp3]=0x1
ft_op[avi]=0x0
ft_op[cr2]=0x0
ft_op[nef]=0x0
ft_op[tiff]=0x0
ft_op[ps]=0x0
ft_op[doc-]=0x200
ft_op[wmv]=0x0
ft_op[psd]=0x0
ft_op[aiff]=0x0
ft_op[flac]=0x0
ft_op[midi]=0x0
ft_op[arc]=0x0
ft_op[bz2]=0x0
ft_op[tar]=0x224
ft_op[ogg]=0x0
ft_op[cab]=0x3
ft_op[gz]=0x13
ft_op[rar]=0x102
ft_op[iso]=0x204
ft_op_scmxofs[iso]=10240
ft_op[docx-]=0x2
ft_op[ott]=0x2
ft_op[odt]=0x2
ft_op[otg]=0x2
ft_op[odg]=0x2
ft_op[otp]=0x2
ft_op[odp]=0x2
ft_op[ots]=0x2
ft_op[ods]=0x2
ft_op[otc]=0x2
ft_op[odc]=0x2
ft_op[oti]=0x2
ft_op[odi]=0x2
ft_op[otf]=0x2
ft_op[odf]=0x2
ft_op[oth]=0x2
ft_op[odm]=0x2
ft_op[apk]=0x2
ft_op[jar]=0x2
ft_op[zip]=0x2
ft_op[zip-null]=0x11
ft_op[mkv]=0x0
ft_op[flv]=0x0
ft_op[mov]=0x0
ft_op[mp4-mov]=0x0
ft_op[mp4]=0x0
ft_op[elf]=0x8
ft_op[dll]=0x0
ft_op[WinPE]=0x10
ft_op[vhd.]=0x8
ft_op[vhd]=0x4
ft_op[vhdx]=0x4
ft_op[vmdk-desc]=0x0
ft_op[pst]=0x0
ft_op[bmp]=0x0
ft_op[mts]=0x200
ft_op[mts-B]=0x210
ft_op[djvu]=0x0
ft_op[docx]=0x2
ft_op[pptx]=0x2
ft_op[xlsx]=0x2
ft_op[doc]=0x200
ft_op[xls]=0x200
ft_op[ppt]=0x200
ft_op[msi]=0x204
ft_op[opt]=0x208
ft_op[thumbs.db]=0x208
ft_op[cdoc-r]=0x9
ft_op[mpeg-A]=0x300
ft_op[mpeg-B]=0x300
ft_op[mpeg-C]=0x300
ft_op[mov-B]=0x0
ft_op[crw]=0x0
ft_op[srw]=0x0
ft_op[raf]=0x0
ft_op[orf]=0x0
ft_op[jpeg-B]=0x0
ft_op[mp3-B]=0x261
ft_op[cr3]=0x0
ft_op[heic]=0x0
ft_op[Archives]=0x10
ft_op[Documents]=0x10
ft_op[Graphics]=0x10
ft_op[Media]=0x10
ft_op[Text]=0x10
ft_op[DiskImages]=0x10
ft_op[Executable]=0x10
ft_op[Other]=0x10
ft_op[Removed]=0x10
ft_op[Spec.]=0x10
ft_sort="102;Archives,7z,arc,bz2,cab,gz,rar,tar,zip,zip-null,Documents,chm,djvu,\
doc,doc-,docx,docx-,odc,odf,odg,odi,odm,odp,ods,odt,opt,otc,otf,otg,oth,oti,otp,\
ots,ott,pdf,ppt,pptx,ps,pst,rtf,xls,xlsx,Graphics,bmp,cr2,cr3,crw,gif,heic,jpeg,\
jpeg-B,nef,orf,png,psd,raf,srw,tiff,Media,aiff,avi,flac,flv,midi,mkv,mov,mov-B,mp3,\
mp3-B,mp4,mp4-mov,mpeg-A,mpeg-B,mpeg-C,mts,mts-B,ogg,wav,wmv,Text,html,reg,xml,DiskImages,\
iso,vdi,vhd,vhd.,vhdx,vmdk,vmdk-desc,Executable,apk,dll,elf,exe-DOS,exe-Win,jar,\
msi,WinPE,Other,thumbs.db,"
ft[.]=!"953862;200:200000k00{.+*e8e04"

[ntfsscan3.1]
scan_dev=1:0:11:-1:0x1:512:7814037168:"\\?\scsi#disk&ven_st4000dm&prod_004-2cv104#a&72eb970&0&000000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}"
scan_vorg=3.4
scan_range="0x0-0x3a3817d6000"
scan_state_sec="block:0x2000;inc:0x4000;first:0x2000;shift:0x2000;sec:0x1d1c0beb0;set:0x0"
scan_flags=0x7
mftsortcol=0
mftsortrev=0
mftcheckmask=0x22c
mftfiltminlen=0
mftfiltmaxlen=0
mftfiltofs=0x0-0x0
mftfiltnum=0-0
MFTRuns="0;"
INDX_recs_times=0
INDX_ofs="0;"
volstartstotnum=0
volstarts="3;0x7e00:1:0x2,0x0:1:0x2,0x200:1:0x2,"
volstartsother=0
maxmftnumallow=2147483647
maxvolsize=0x3a3817d6000
volumes="0;"
scan_vorg=3.4
scan_modltrack=0.0:0x0:3.4:806:0:0x687d3edf3e000
scan_modltrackorg=3.4:806:0x0:0x0
```

it seems this HDD is in bad shape.

I also just checked the built-in Disk Management tool of windows, and it asks to initialize the HDD in question

[Disk Management capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKQZJ.png)

but I think If I do that I'll definitely erase the currently unreadable data ?

Comment: Try examine the drive / volume with DMDE.

Comment: thanks Joep van Steen, I'm going to try that in a few minutes then !

Comment: The disk might have died. See if you can get its SMART attributes and add to your post. If these attributes are inaccessible, it will take a professional recovery specialist to get at any data from it.

Comment: thanks for your help harrymc, I tested it according to your suggestions and provided information in my main message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing the HDD will indeed destroy your data. A failed disk should
not be written-to in any way, if you really need to recover the data.

The disk seems to be dead for all intents and purposes and the data is
lost to you, but not to a company specializing in recovering data from
failed disks.

If the data on the disk is worth paying for recovery services, search
for such a company in your country or area. Recovery specialists are not
simple repair-shops, so avoid those.

Comment: Hi Harrymc, thanks for your answer, yes I won't be able to read anything from this disk without help of a recovery service, I'll then evaluate the need of that process according to the nature of the data that was lost. again thanks for you advices and help, have a nice day.